# Displaying Name while opening the app

Tags: android-studio

I want to make a code to display the name of user when it's saved at the first use, then keep it displaying every time the user lunches the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can save user's name in **SharedPreferences**, display it after and every time user launches your app. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a database to remember user details. See [SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html). Within your launcher activity you can query the database and display the name or prompt the user to enter their name.